# Create and read properly .csv files with specific characters from multiple languages

Tags: r, csv, encoding, utf-8

I'm working with some .csv files containing specific characters from several languages (Russian, Polish, West European, etc.).

Even if once I read the file and apply the necessary changes so everything shows up properly in the table so it can look like this:

```
city                country
Kyiv Левый          Ukraine
Cádiz               Spain
Poznań              Poland
```

Once I'm saving the file  `write.csv(cities, 'cities.csv', fileEncoding = 'UTF-8')`, if I try to read again the file in a new session I'm getting again this non-desired output:

```
cities <- read_csv('cities.csv')
city                                                 country
Kyiv <U+041B><U+0435><U+0432><U+044B><U+0439>        Ukraine
Cádiz                                                Spain
Poznan                                               Poland
```

As you will notice, the only characters that right now it's supporting are the Spanish ones (I guess due to my regional configuration), however I need R to create the CSV respecting all characters. Is this possible? If so, how should I do?

Comment: You can check the locale settings

Comment: I did, but don't know how to do in order to create a CSV supporting diverse alphabets such the ones in the example.

Comment: Furthermore, is there a way to set multiple locales so we can create and/or read .csv files respecting multiple alphabets?